# Cropping an image to a minimum bounding box for a set of points

Tags: image-processing, image

Imagine a define a pointlist inside of an image:

[image]

Provided a pointlist for the set of red dots around the toy horse, is there a way for me to automatically crop to a minimum bounding box for this set of points?

Comment: "The Proof"?...

Comment: @MichaelE2 Oh yes - that toy horse is certainly unmistakable.  There's also Andrew Wiles on the left.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ImageTrim[image, pointList]` does just that

Comment: Terrific - sorry I missed that.